# GCP Cloud Function failed to deploy due to duplicate name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I deleted my cloud function and try to deploy a new one with the same name but keep getting the following error:

**Function currentTime in region europe-central2 in project xxx already exists.**

Changing region doesn't help as it keeps failing to deploy. What could be the reason? I deleted all of my functions just to be sure. And when I try to delete function from terminal using the following command;

```
firebase functions:delete currentTime --project xxx
```

I get the following warning which means there are no functions named currentTime in my project:

**Error: The specified filters do not match any existing functions in project sanal-bet.**

Answer (score 1):

I think you not deleted correctly your `Cloud Function`.

To delete correctly your function, you should use [gcloud function delete command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/delete)

```bash
gcloud functions delete your-function-name --region=REGION
```

You can also delete your function directly in the console in the `Cloud Function` menu :

[image]